# How Many Pixels Per Inch to Make A Detailed Desktop Wallpaper?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What is the highest, most reasonably possible number of pixels I should write in the image making options of Photoshop if I want a *really* high resolution image that I can present in several downgraded versions?

Don't give me 1920 x 1050 or any other ratios like this, please. There already is a thread like this which has not answered my question.

[image: Resolution: 72 pixels per inch enough for such a big image, or not?]

Comment: What is your actual question? The highest is size in pixels (width/height) or the highest resolution (ppi)?

Answer (score 3):

Wellcome, but your question is a contradiction.

> How Many Pixels Per Inch to Make A Detailed Desktop Wallpaper?

PPI **does not** matter at all on an electronic device.

> Don't give me 1920 x 1050 or any other ratios like this, please.

In an electronic medium you need to use simple pixels as a unit. So the answer is something like... 1920x1080, 4k. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution or 8K https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8K_resolution (7680 × 4320 px)

Some IMac have a resolution of 5k (5120‑by‑2880 px): www.apple.com/imac/

I do not know which thread did not answered the way you expected. But this is the answer.

Comment: You might add that for legacy conversion reasons you should stay at 72 PPI that way your unit conversion match those of illustrator when doing pixel images and some browsers.

Answer (score -3):

I'd go for 150 so it can fit retina screens as well